# jqgrid, send a query string to my data.php file

Tags: php, jqgrid

Hi I'm using jqgrid to show some information in a grid. But I have a problem and I don't know how to solve.

I have the following function to fill my jqgrid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'data.php?q=1',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Fabricante','Codigo', 'Titulo','Descripcion'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'fabricante', index:'fabricante', width:137}, 
      {name:'codigo', index:'codigo', width:100}, 
      {name:'titulo', index:'titulo', width:250}, 
      {name:'descripcion', index:'descripcion', width:400}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:1000,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'invid',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: "256px",
    caption: 'Cursos'
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

this is my body:

```
<form name="form" action="CourseSearch.html" method="get">
   <input type="text" class="search-fields" id="fab"/>
   <input class="" type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Search" />
</form>
<table id="list">
    <tr>
        <td><td/>
    </tr>
</table> 
<div id="pager">
</div>
```

I just want to know how to send a string to my data.php page using my html form, because I need to get this string to using in the mysql query to get the data.

Thanks

---

This is the new code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#search').click(function () {
    $("#list").trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: 1, current: true}]);
  });
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'data.php?q=1',
    postData: {
        mySearch: function () { return $('#fab').val(); }
    },
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'get',
    colNames:['Fabricante','Codigo', 'Titulo','Descripcion'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'fabricante', index:'fabricante', width:137}, 
      {name:'codigo', index:'codigo', width:100}, 
      {name:'titulo', index:'titulo', width:250}, 
      {name:'descripcion', index:'descripcion', width:400}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:1000,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'invid',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: "256px",
    caption: 'Cursos'
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

---

Another change

the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#search').click(function () {
    $("#list").trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: 1, current: true}]);
    return false;
  });
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'data.php?',
    postData: {q: 1, mySearch: function () { return $('#fab').val(); }},
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'get',
    colNames:['Fabricante','Codigo', 'Titulo','Descripcion'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'fabricante', index:'fabricante', width:137}, 
      {name:'codigo', index:'codigo', width:100}, 
      {name:'titulo', index:'titulo', width:250}, 
      {name:'descripcion', index:'descripcion', width:400}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:1000,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'invid',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: "256px",
    caption: 'Cursos'
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

the new form

```
<fieldset style="border: none;">
   <input type="text" class="search-fields" id="fab"/>
   <input class="" type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Search" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want refresh grid using the input field `#fab` on the click on the "Submit2" button.

Because you don't need to send any parameters directly to an URL you can first change the code of the form to

Search

As a handler for the click event on the "Search" button you can do

```js
$('#search').click(function () {
    $("#list").trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: 1, current: true}]);
});
```

At the end you need add to jqGrid additional `postData` parameter like the following

```js
postData: {
    mySearch: function () { return $('#fab').val(); }
}
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for more information). In the case the parameter `mySearch` will be send to the URL `'data.php?q=1'`. Because you used `mtype: 'GET'` the parameter will be appended to the URL like `'data.php?q=1&mySearch=test'` for example

Comment: @Jean: I don't use PHP myself, but I suppose that the code could be like `$mySearch = $_REQUEST['mySearch'];`. You cab download some examples from [the page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). [The demo files](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/downloads/jqgrid_demo40.zip) includes some PHP code.

Comment: perfect that's what I thought. but I have problem with the postData. Thanks anyway for your help. I'll try to do other things.

Comment: I try this, but I doesn't work even if I have the following url, the grid is empty, for example I just want all the product that contain the word microsoft so I sent this url: url:'data.php?Microsoft', do you have any idea?

Comment: @Jean: How you want to get the word 'Microsoft' from the URL: `url: 'data.php?Microsoft'`? Probably you should use `url: 'data.php?mySearch=Microsoft'`? The usage of `postData: {mySearch: 'Microsoft'}` will do the same.

Comment: I think the problem is that I don't know where to put the postData :S

Comment: @Jean: `postData` is just an [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) of jqGrid. So you can just mix it with other jqGrid options:  `$("#list").jqGrid({url: 'data.php', postData: {q:1, mySearch: 'Microsoft'}, datatype: 'xml', mtype: 'GET',...});`

Comment: I so sorry Oleg, but I desperate, can I publish the code, so you can check ir. Please???

Comment: @Jean: Yes, of course! If you append your new code to your question, please let me this known in the comment.

Comment: @Jean: The main part of the code seems be correct. You can even use `url: 'data.php', postData: {q: 1, mySearch: function () { return $('#fab').val(); }}`. The problem I see only because of `type="submit"` of the 'Search' button. You should use `$('#search').submit` instead of `$('#search').click` and `return false` to prevent the `action="CourseSearch.html" method="get"` which will load another page instead of refreshing the body of the grid on the current page. I wrote about the problem in the first line of my answer. I use typically `type='button'`, `click` and `fieldset` instead of `form`.

Comment: @Jean: in you new code you use `$('#search').click`. Where the HTML code with the `<button>` or `<input>` having `id="search"`? Instead of that your HTML code contains `<input class="" type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Search" />` So if you press the "Search" button no `$('#search').click` will be called. Instead of this will be opened the page `CourseSearch.html` with some additional parameters from the form.